# How do you change what the Eclipse debugger displays for an object in the Variables pane?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do you change what the Eclipse debugger displays for a Java object in the Variables pane?  I'd like to provide a custom string to put there for my objects so I don't have to keep clicking on them.  The default of SomeClass (id=111111...) isn't very useful.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [detail formatters](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t16350.html).

Comment: And the detail formatters (Preferences > Java > Debug > Detail Formatters) allows you to change the default display to the toString() value for each object.  Usually that's good enough for me.  Thanks!